# Can I define a set of files in filezilla that I want to transfer?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have a set of programs in different directories that I work on all the time and I upload them to a server all  the time. So I have to move from folder to folder uploading the programs in that directory.

I would like to define the set somewhere and be able to transfer just those programs (not the whole system) at one time. Can I do it in filezilla? Is there another ftp program that will allow that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you may want to consider just setting up a batch file that does it (or a shell script on Unix/Linux)

The command line ftp command is more powerful than most realize.

Of particular note is the following switch from the Windows command line ftp:

```
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
```

I don't think Filezilla lets you do this, though.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think so. I was hoping though/